# SPD approval workflow one IF condition is not available

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, approval, sharepoint-designer-workflow, if-condition

I'm an new for sharepoint. Recently I created an approval workflow with SPD. There are multiple filter condition in the worklfow to filter the application to use the right approval process.
But when I submitted an application, I found one filter condition is not available in the workflow. 
[image: my workflow]For example when the approval process A finished, it will continue to start process B, actually the application which I submitted only meet the process A's condition.(please refer to the attached screenshot)
It seems the IF condition "If Current Item:Annual Plan Training equals (ignoring case) Out of annual training plan/年度培训计划外" is not working. 
Can anyone give me some ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, it seems that you are placing the if condition in a sequence. So the workflow will simply go through all the if condition on by one. That is why after Process A is finished, the Process B will be initiated.

It will be better for you to use If-else structure with nested IF to re-construct your workflow.

Reference:https://support.office.com/en-us/article/workflow-conditions-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-a-quick-reference-guide-d8e33ac7-9336-487f-a60b-388c4ea497ff